# How to represent the Spring Security "custom-filter" using Java configuration?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-java-config

What is the equivalent Java configuration for the Spring Security `<custom-filter>` tag?

```xml
<http>
  <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter"/>
</http>
```

I tried

```java
http.addFilter( new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() )
```

where the class extends the default filter, but it always employs the `formLogin` default.

My filter:

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication; 
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{

    // proof of concept of how the http.addFilter() works

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        System.out.println("running my own version of UsernmePasswordFilter ... ");

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
}
```

The relevant configuration piece:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity  // annotate class configuring AuthenticationManagerBuilder
@ComponentScan("com.kayjed")
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**","/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();

      http.addFilter(new MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter());
    }

    ...
}
```

Running the MVC app in the debugger always shows the login attempts authentication from the default `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` instead of my intention of employing the `MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class.

Anyways, I am not trying to get someone to debug code; rather, I would love to see a good example using Java configuration that performs the equivalent of the custom-filter element in the XML approach.   The documentation is a bit terse.

Comment: Please post your entire configuration and describe what you  mean by "it always employs the formLogin default"

Answer (score 33):

A few issues you may need to keep in mind:

1. Your filter needs to be added **before** the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

   ```java
   http.addFilterBefore(customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(),
           UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
   ```
2. If you extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter your filter will return immediately without doing anything unless you set a `RequestMatcher`

   ```java
   myAuthFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
       new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
   ```
3. All the configuration you do in `http.formLogin().x().y().z()` is applied to the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` not the custom filter you build.  You will need to configure it manually yourself.  My auth filter initialization looks like this:

   ```java
   @Bean
   public MyAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
       MyAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new MyAuthenticationFilter();
       authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));
       authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
       authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new MySuccessHandler("/app"));
       authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new MyFailureHandler("/login?error=1"));
       authFilter.setUsernameParameter("username");
       authFilter.setPasswordParameter("password");
       return authFilter;
   }
   ```

Comment: You can also get *default* AuthenticationManager instance injected through overriden setAuthenticationManager() setter of MyAuthenticationFilter.

Comment: @Altair7852 Could you share a project about MyAuthenticationFilter

Comment: @noodles, MyAuthenticationFilter is his implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

Answer (score 4):

I dont find any issue in this code. I think, your configuration is fine. Problem is somewhere else.I have similar code,

```
package com.programsji.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.programsji.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import com.programsji.security.CustomSuccessHandler;
import com.programsji.security.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/theme/**").and()
                .debug(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                .setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                .setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customSuccessHandler());
        return customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler() {
        CustomSuccessHandler customSuccessHandler = new CustomSuccessHandler();
        return customSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider() {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        return customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviderList = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
        authenticationProviderList.add(customAuthenticationProvider());
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new ProviderManager(
                authenticationProviderList);
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/reportspage").hasRole("REPORT")
                .antMatchers("/rawdatapage").hasRole("RAWDATA").anyRequest()
                .hasRole("USER").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .usernameParameter("j_username").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll().and().httpBasic().and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf().disable()
                .addFilter(customUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter());
    }

}
```

It is working fine on my application.
you can download this entire project from url:
https://github.com/programsji/rohit/tree/master/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: The link you've provided is offline.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `@Component` to your `MyUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class.

This annotation makes the class considered as candidates for auto-detection, see:
[@Component](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)

---

For this:

```
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myFilter"/>
```

You can add this:

```
.addFilter[Before|After](authenticationTokenProcessingFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
```

See: [Standard Filter Aliases and Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think this solves the problem?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I am looking for the exact same thing. Thank you for sharing your solution, if you have any.