# Allow spring security login for every domains

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am trying to make login in my spring web application.
I am using spring security and when i try to make login in a different IP, i get the next error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/OVDigital/j_spring_security_check. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.6:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

What i can do to solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

This correct default behavior from security point of view.
Simply put what you have to do is to implement custom [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) filter for that. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) is a simple guide how to do it.

Comment: I need to put this filter in web.xml or in spring security config? thanks

Comment: It has to go into spring security config

Comment: but i have many configurations in spring security config. How i configure my spring security context with Cors Filter? thanks

Comment: Just add your CORS filter to spring config. Take a look at this post, it tells how to add filters in both java config and xml config, as I am not sure which one you have. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122586/how-to-represent-the-spring-security-custom-filter-using-java-configuration

Comment: I have xml config. I will try to follow that configuration in my project